# Function that extracts data at specific indexes by passing indexes and numpy array as parameters, while being able to handle variations in dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to make a function that can pass in a numpy array (with no restrictions on shape/dimensions) and the indexes from where I want to extract data.

Here is a simple example of some sample arrays, and what the function should return for a given input.

```
 x = np.array( [ [2,3,1], [2, 1, 1], ], [ [5, 3, 1],  [6, 2, 4] ]  )
 y = np.array( [ [2,3,1], [2, 1, 1]]  )
 z = np.array( [2,3,1] )

def getdata( indexes, array):
    #Something

getdata( [1, 0, 1], x )
#should return
# 3

getdata( [0, 1], x )
#should return
# array([2, 1, 1])

getdata( [1, 0], y )
#should return
# 2

getdata( [2], z )
#should return
# 1
```

The indexes do Not have to be inserted using lists, any method can be used.

Comment: I mean, you could write one, but surely such a function would be slow (for large data sets) and thus not very useful?

Comment: why would it be slower? Is there anything that adds to the execution time, other than calling the function itself?

Comment: Actually, you can just do `x[(1, 0, 1)]`

Comment: Looks like it's not as bad as I thought... `timeit('y = x[(1, 0, 1)]', setup='import numpy as np; x = np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))', number=1000000)` == 0.15 on my PC

Comment: it could be a couple dozen times a second. I am creating a data processing program, and want the user to be able to extract data from the processes. Your solution worked. If you submit it as an answer i'll mark it as answr

Comment: `x[1,0,1]` is the same as `x[(1,0,1)]`.  If `idx` is a list, `x[tuple(idx)]` should index it right.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy indexing allow you to do this:

```
x = np.array( [ [2,3,1], [2, 1, 1], ], [ [5, 3, 1],  [6, 2, 4] ]  )
y = np.array( [ [2,3,1], [2, 1, 1]]  )
z = np.array( [2,3,1] )
#example:
d=x[1,0,1]#returns 3
```

like a normal list with 3 dimensions.
so if all of the indexes you use match the array shape, you can just do this:

```
data=x[indexes]
```

But in addition you can do this with numpy arrays:

```
data=x[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]] #data=[[2,3,1],[6,2,4],[2,3,1]]
```

which is the same as:

```
data=np.array([x[0,0],x[1,1],x[0,0]])
```